# middle value of each subarray

Tags: java, recursion

The following error shows:
at parenthesis.check.printcombination(check.java:51)

at parenthesis.check.printcombination(check.java:58) 
My 51st and 56th  line are commented below in the code

```
package parenthesis;

import java.util.*;

public class check {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };

        function(arr, 0, 7);
    }

    public static void function(int arr[], int start, int end) {
        int mid;

        mid = (start + end) / 2;

        printcombination(arr, start, end, mid);
    }

    public static void printcombination(int arr[], int start, int end, int mid) {

        System.out.print(arr[mid] + " "); //// error

        if ((start == mid) && (mid == end)) {
            return;
        }

        printcombination(arr, start, mid - 1, (start + mid - 1) / 2); //// error

        printcombination(arr, mid + 1, end, (mid + 1 + end) / 2);

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement some sort of binary function ?

Comment: what r u trying to do. We can help better if you say that

Comment: What's the rest of the error?  Did you try debugging?  Also, format the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: It looks like you are having a problem related to checking the bounds on the recursive calls in a variation of a binary search function?  You might want to add what the error IS that is occurring on those lines, and it is also unclear why you mention an error at 58 and a comment at 56.

Comment: This appears to be a course assignment.

Comment: The output should be 15 13 12 14 17 16 18 19 that is middle value of each subarray

Answer (score 1):

There is a bad recursion at line 34 ("printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2); ////error"), StackOverflowError error is thrown here. 
Recursion flow for "printcombination" method is:

start = 0, mid = 3, end = 7, call "printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2)";

start = 0, mid = 1, end = 2, call "printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2)";

start = 0, mid = 0, end = 0, return;

start = 0, mid = 1, end = 2, call "printcombination(arr,mid+1,end,(mid+1+end)/2);

start = 0, mid = 3, end = 7, call printcombination(arr,mid+1,end,(mid+1+end)/2);

start = 4, mid = 5, end = 7, call "printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2)";

start = 4, mid = 4, end = 4, return;

start = 4, mid = 5, end = 7, call "printcombination(arr,mid+1,end,(mid+1+end)/2)";

start = 6, mid = 6, end = 7, call "printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2)";

start = 6, mid = 5, end = 5, call "printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2)";

start = 6, mid = 5, end = 4, call "printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2)";

start = 6, mid = 5, end = 4, call "printcombination(arr,start,mid-1,(start+mid-1)/2)";

...

Answer (score 0):

Try or instead of and: `if((start==mid)||(mid==end))`